# Pinescript can't handle division comparisons?

Tags: pine-script

the following script should produce labels on top and bottom of the same bars. But `mySeries1` puts under every bar a label. Can't pinescript handle this or am I doing something wrong?

```
//@version=4
study(title = "Division?", overlay=true)

labelPosLow = low - (atr(30) * 0.6)
labelPosHigh = high + (atr(30) * 0.6)

totalLength = high - low

mySeries1 = close - low >= 1/2 * totalLength 
if mySeries1
    label.new(bar_index, labelPosLow, text="A", style=label.style_label_up, color = color.blue, textcolor=color.white)
    
mySeries2 = close - low >= 0.5 * totalLength 
if mySeries2
    label.new(bar_index, labelPosHigh, text="B", style=label.style_label_down, color = color.green, textcolor=color.white)
```

[image: Pinescript chart]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what you trying to do or if you know that 1/2 is not equal to 0.5 in pine script. Change 1/2 to 1.0/2.0, this may work

Comment: Actually I was not aware, that 1/2 is not equal to 0.5. Thanks mate!